# SPATSTAT duplicated points within a a specific distance

Tags: r, duplicates, spatstat

I have a dataset in R studio of settlements that are coordinates and I am trying to delete duplicated points that lie within a certain distance of each other  i.e 20 meters.
Any idea?
Thanks

> winch2<- data.frame(Lon=c(-1.560367, -1.078330 ), Lat=c(
> 50.576342, 51.243823)) coordinates(winch2) <- ~Lon + Lat proj4string(winch2) <- latlong winch2 <- spTransform(winch2, bng)
> (floor (coordinates (winch2) / 1000) + 0.5) * 1000 W2<-
> owin(c(431500,464500), c( 75500, 149500)) Region<- allpop_strat[W2]
>
> Subset from a bigger Window of points
>
> summary(Region)
>
> Marked planar point pattern:  371 points Average intensity
> 1.519247e-07 points per square unit
>
> Coordinates are given to 2 decimal places i.e. rounded to the nearest
> multiple of 0.01 units
>
> marks are numeric, of type ‘double’ Summary:    Min. 1st Qu.  Median
> Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
> 0.0100  0.0100  0.0100  0.4078  1.0000  6.0000
>
> Window: rectangle = [431500, 464500] x [75500, 149500] units Window
> area = 2.442e+09 square units
>
> anyDuplicated(Region) 0
>
> But I want any duplicated within a specific distanve

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the code you have tried to get this working?

Comment: Yes ill add it above

Comment: The very messy code above cannot be run in a fresh R session. Please provide all relevant commands on separate lines (including loading packages), so it can be copy/pasted into a new R session.

Comment: Could you also specify which point you want to keep if several points are within distance 20 meters of each other? Imagine three points on a line with 15 meters between each. Should they be replaced by a single point in the middle or by two points (one in each end)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple case when close points just appear in pairs the code below
should be sufficient to delete close neighbours. What is deleted depends
on the ordering of the points. If many points are within distance `R`
(e.g. 20 m) of each other there are probably many solutions to the
problem and the code below may or may not produce what you need.

```r
library(spatstat)
X <- unmark(amacrine) # Built-in dataset for demonstation
R <- 0.03 # Distance of "close pairs"
close_list = closepairs(X, rmax = R, twice = FALSE)
close_index <- close_list$j
plot(X, main = "Test data with points to be deleted in red")
plot(X[close_index], col = "red", pch = 20, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
Y <- X[-close_index]
plot(Y, main = "Retained points after removal of close points.")
```

[image]